# MTU changing after first ping

Tags: ping, mtu

I noticed kind of strange behaviour and my knowledge doesn't have answer for it.
So I want to know MTU. First ping:

```
ping -c 1 -s 1800 -M do google.com
PING google.com (216.58.209.14) 1800(1828) bytes of data.
ping: local error: Message too long, mtu=1500

--- google.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, +1 errors, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

So I conclude that MTU is 1500. But after sending 1472 bytes I get:

```
ping -c 1 -s 1472 -M do google.com
PING google.com (216.58.209.14) 1472(1500) bytes of data.
From 192.168.55.1 (192.168.55.1) icmp_seq=1 Frag needed and DF set (mtu = 0)

--- google.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, +1 errors, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

And then:

```
ping -c 1 -s 1500 -M do google.com
PING google.com (216.58.209.14) 1500(1528) bytes of data.
ping: local error: Message too long, mtu=552

--- google.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, +1 errors, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

Why it changed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Confusion about MTU](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/68927/confusion-about-mtu)

Comment: @Zac67 I think it does ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-M do` sets the *Don't fragment* bit (DF), so you can only successfully ping when not exceeding the path MTU.

`-s 1472` for a total packet size of 1500 is the largest ping payload that works *over plain Ethernet*. Protocols like PPPoE eat into that, so a router in the path reports MTU exceeded and there's no echo reply.

You cannot even locally send `-s 1500` without fragmention since `-s` specifies the optional *payload* for the ICMP echo request. The IP packet header is 20 bytes, the ICMP header 8 bytes, so 1472 bytes is the largest ping payload for plain Ethernet.

Comment: so where does 552 come from?